# Where to place $(document).ready(function(){ properly in wordpress?

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, include

I am trying to add that [library](http://callmenick.com/post/image-overlay-hover-effects-with-css3-transitions) to wordpress. 
So I have added all the CSS and JavaScript libraries to Wordpress. 
Now I have to run some Java code that will be executed when the following function is called.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        if (Modernizr.touch) {
            // show the close overlay button
            $(".close-overlay").removeClass("hidden");
            // handle the adding of hover class when clicked
            $(".img").click(function(e){
                if (!$(this).hasClass("hover")) {
                    $(this).addClass("hover");
                }
            });
            // handle the closing of the overlay
            $(".close-overlay").click(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                e.stopPropagation();
                if ($(this).closest(".img").hasClass("hover")) {
                    $(this).closest(".img").removeClass("hover");
                }
            });
        } else {
            // handle the mouseenter functionality
            $(".img").mouseenter(function(){
                $(this).addClass("hover");
            })
            // handle the mouseleave functionality
            .mouseleave(function(){
                $(this).removeClass("hover");
            });
        }
    });
```

How can I add that to my page?

Answer (score 0):

You should add this code in one file and add with `wp_enqueue_scripts`.

`function scripts_styles() {`

Add javascript with `wp_enqueue_script`
`wp_enqueue_script( 'script-id', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/main.js', array( 'jquery' ));`

Add CSS with `wp_enqueue_style`
    `wp_enqueue_style( 'all-theme', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/style.css.css');`

`}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'scripts_styles' );`